# What is the better for call files: bloginfo() or echo esc_url()?

Tags: functions, references

Using the [Theme Check](http://themecheck.org/) for test the quality of my theme, it return my theme is using the `bloginfo();` 
 Ex: `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/static/img/logo.svg"`

The Theme Check recommended that I replace the `bloginfo()` for `echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );`

I searched about it, but I'm not sure if using this function is a good practice.

So, it's correct use `echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );` for call any files in my theme?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `bloginfo('template_url')` is a [wrapper](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) for `get_template_directory_uri()`.

It doesn't seems to explicitly escape it, though.

It's better to escape it in your example.

Here are two examples how we can break the HTML in the case it's not escaped:

**Break Example #1**

```
add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', function( $uri )
{
    return $uri .'">';
} );
```

**Break Example #2**

```
add_filter( 'bloginfo_url', function( $output )
{
    return $output .'">';
} );
```

So the suggestion:

```
echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() );
```

is safer than use it unescaped.

The `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` are commonly used core functions, where the latter is *child-theme* aware.

**New functions in WordPress 4.7**

There will be new functions introduced to e.g. make it easier to reference and override parent theme files

Let's take a look inside two of them:

- The new `get_theme_file_uri( $file )` function is *child-theme* aware and uses both`get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to construct the correct file URL.

  ```
  if ( empty( $file ) ) {
      $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
  } elseif ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file ) ) {
      $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;
  } else {
      $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;
  }
  ```

  where `$file` is the function's input.

  Let's try to describe the above logic in few words, to better understand it:

  - For an empty file input, `get_theme_file_uri()`, it's the same as: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.
  - If there's a child theme that overrides the file, then it's `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;`
  - If there's a child theme that doesn't override the file (it doesn't exist in the child theme ) then it's the parent file fallback: `get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;`
  - If there's no child theme and the file exists, then it's `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;`
  - If there's no child theme, and the file doesn't exists, then it's `get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;`
- The new `get_parent_theme_file_uri( $file )` function, on the other hand, uses only `get_template_directory_uri()`:

  ```
  if ( empty( $file ) ) {
      $url = get_template_directory_uri();
  } else {
      $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $file;
  }
  ```

  This is to construct the file URL within the parent theme, as the name suggests.
- Similarly there are corresponding functions for the *path* instead of *url*: `get_file_directory_path()` and `get_parent_file_directory_path()`.

We should also note that it doesn't matter if `$file` starts with a forward slash `/` or not, that's taken care of with a masked `ltrim`:

```
$file = ltrim( $file, '/' );
```

See ticket [#18302](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18302) for more info.

**Example:**

So in WordPress 4.7+ we could try:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_file_uri('static/img/logo.svg') ); ?>">
```

or for the parent theme file location, depending on the needs:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_parent_theme_file_uri('static/img/logo.svg') ); ?>">
```

It would be nice though to have the corresponding `the_*` functions as well to simplify things:

```
<img src="<?php the_theme_file_uri('static/img/logo.svg') ); ?>">

<img src="<?php the_parent_theme_file_uri('static/img/logo.svg') ); ?>">
```

where they would include the escaping, similar to how `the_permalink()` escapes the filtered output from `get_permalink()`.